NestJS with microservice does not generate dist/apps/<service>/main.js in build docker-compose
I create NestJS with microservices, in development mode on my PC everything works ...
docker compose -f docker-compose.dev.yml up --build

docker-compose.dev.yml is here
services:
  gateway:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./apps/gateway/Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app
      - /usr/src/app/node_modules
    ports:
      - 3006:3006
    depends_on:
      - redis
    command: npm run start:dev

  auth:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./apps/auth/Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app
      - /usr/src/app/node_modules
    depends_on:
      - redis
    command: npm run start:dev auth

  .... next services ...

Dockerfile of auth service is here ...
FROM node:18.19.0-alpine

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package*.json ./
COPY tsconfig.json ./
COPY tsconfig.build.json ./

RUN npm install
RUN npm run build auth

COPY . .

BUT! if I run docker compose for build services, not main.js does not created, in dist/apps//main.js.
I run docker compose -f docker-compose.yml build
docker-compose.yml is here
services:
  gateway:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./apps/gateway/Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app
      - /usr/src/app/node_modules
    ports:
      - "3006:3006"
    command: node dist/apps/gateway/main.js
    env_file:
      - .env

  auth:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./apps/auth/Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app
      - /usr/src/app/node_modules
    command: node dist/apps/auth/main.js
    env_file:
      - .env
  ... next services ...


And here is nest-cli.json file
{
  "$schema": "https://json.schemastore.org/nest-cli",
  "collection": "@nestjs/schematics",
  "sourceRoot": ".",
  "entryFile": "main",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "webpack": true,
    "tsConfigPath": "apps/gateway/tsconfig.app.json"
  },
  "monorepo": true,
  "root": "apps/gateway",
  "projects": {
    "gateway": {
      "type": "application",
      "root": "apps/gateway",
      "entryFile": "main",
      "sourceRoot": "apps/gateway/src",
      "compilerOptions": {
        "tsConfigPath": "apps/gateway/tsconfig.app.json"
      }
    },
    "auth": {
      "type": "application",
      "root": "apps/auth",
      "entryFile": "main",
      "sourceRoot": "apps/auth/src",
      "compilerOptions": {
        "tsConfigPath": "apps/auth/tsconfig.app.json"
      }
    },
    ... next services ...

No docker container starts, because no of dist/apps//main.js files not exists. Folder could created, but nothing is in.
Can anybody help me?
I don't know, where is a problem. I try many changes in tsconfig.json file, but nothing works.
Problem is in my pc and in GitLab CI/CD, here is gitlab-ci.yml
stages:
  - build
  - deploy

variables:
  TAG_LATEST: $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE/$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME:latest
  TAG_COMMIT: $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE/$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME:$CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA
  PROJECT_FOLDER: /var/www/.../server-microservice

build:
  image: docker:latest
  stage: build
  services:
    - docker:dind
  before_script:
    - docker info
    - docker compose --version
  script:
    - echo "Building Docker images"
    - docker login -u gitlab-ci-token -p $CI_JOB_TOKEN $CI_REGISTRY
    - echo "Docker login successful!"
    - docker compose -f docker-compose.dev.yml build
    - echo "Pushing Docker images to registry"
    - docker compose push --quiet
  only:
    - main
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - dist/*

deploy:
  image: alpine:latest
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - chmod og= $ID_RSA
    - apk update && apk add openssh-client
    - scp -i $ID_RSA -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no ./.env $SERVER_USER@$SERVER_IP:$PROJECT_FOLDER/.env
    - scp -i $ID_RSA -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no ./docker-compose.yml $SERVER_USER@$SERVER_IP:$PROJECT_FOLDER/docker-compose.yml
    - ssh -i $ID_RSA -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $SERVER_USER@$SERVER_IP "chmod 777 $PROJECT_FOLDER/.env"
    - ssh -i $ID_RSA -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $SERVER_USER@$SERVER_IP "chmod 777 $PROJECT_FOLDER/docker-compose.yml"
    - ssh -i $ID_RSA -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $SERVER_USER@$SERVER_IP "which docker"
    - ssh -i $ID_RSA -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $SERVER_USER@$SERVER_IP "docker --version"
    - ssh -i $ID_RSA -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $SERVER_USER@$SERVER_IP "docker login -u gitlab-ci-token -p $CI_JOB_TOKEN $CI_REGISTRY"
    - ssh -i $ID_RSA -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $SERVER_USER@$SERVER_IP "cd $PROJECT_FOLDER && docker compose pull --quiet && docker compose down && docker compose up -d"
  environment:
    name: development
    url: http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
  only:
    - main


In your Dockerfile, you build before COPY . ., I believe you should try to copy first. Also in your gitlab-ci build stage, you're doing docker compose -f docker-compose.dev.yml build, why using .dev file and not a production one ?
